# Laravel авторизация и аутентификация

Tags: php, laravel

Я понимаю что и школа давалась мне тяжко, и понять документацию и её полноту не могу. Даже не понимаю. Вот авторизация пользователя:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('login', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            $token = Auth::user()->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;
            return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'token' => $token]);
        }

        return response()->json(['success'=>false]);
    }
}
```

`Auth::attempt($credentials)` -- происходит аутентификация пользователя. Я могу сохранять токен в куках и проверять каждый раз есть ли токен у пользователя для доступа к страницам сайта. Но потом понял что токен не обязателен. Тогда зачем он вообще? И когда пишу:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

После аутентификации пользователя все равно не впускает на страницу `/user`. Может беда с бд? Оно у меня вот такое:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('login', 45)->unique()->nullable();
            $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin', 'developer', 'salesman'])->default('user');
            $table->string('email', 56)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

И как получать тогда данные пользователя? Например отображать его всегда в `header`если он авторизован. Как создать такую логику -- что бы каждая страница если пользователь авторизован получать данные и отображать в `header`. Но авторизацию не работает, что не так?

Comment: Сайт обычный или API какое-то?

Comment: @InDevX обычный сайт

Comment: @InDevX хотя, сейчас я раскомментировал строчку:  `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,` в Kernel.dll, в app/Http/Kernel.dll. И получается я могу брать авторизованного пользователя, он сохраняется после авторизации, но не понимаю где, и тогда зачем нужен токен в `plainTextToken`?

Comment: sanctum авторизует HTTP запросы этим токеном, он передаётся в Authorization заголовке, это для API, для обычного веба авторизация через сессию в cookie происходит, и sanctum для этого не нужен, там либо доставить можно starter kit, либо самому написать можно авторизацию

Comment: @InDevX я читал про передачу токена в  Authorization. Получается токен где-то надо хранить. Это наверное можно делать в куках. Но как можно его передавать в Authorization в запрос api?

Comment: Храниться на фронте он должен, в local storage чаще всего это делают...  И при запросах к API его отправляют в заголовке Authorization. Вы обычную авторизацию путаете с API авторизацией

Comment: @InDevX если он будет хранится в local storage, мне придется передавать токен в api запросы с помощи JavaScript, например с помощи ajax? И этот токен брать с заголовка Authorization, проверять на валидность и выполнять запрос? Наверное это все таки и есть

Comment: _придется передавать токен в api запросы с помощи JavaScript, например с помощи ajax?_ - да. брать ничего нигде не надо, sanctum всё сам сделает, к роутам только middleware добавить нужно.

Comment: @InDevX о, спасибо вам больше. Просто над авторизацией уже мучаюсь 4 дня, вы хорошо помогли

Comment: Но это же для API авторизация) А вы выше писали что для обычного сайта нужно, они разные